# Abstract class with different derived signatures in Python

Tags: python, object-oriented

I don't feel too comfortable with the use of object oriented programming and the related advanced topics. That's why I went through this exercise of using Python's abstract class to implement an abstract [Ansatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansatz) class. (An Ansatz is basically something like a mathematical assumption, i.e. we might assume that our solution looks like a polynomial or like a logistic function).

Since different Ansätze might have different signatures, I wanted to be somewhat generic. Some Ansätze might just get a few scalar parameters, others arrays, yet others a mix of both.

All derived classes need to implement the `eval` function, which evaluates the Ansatz for a given input.

For all Ansätze, I want to be able to optimally fit the parameters to match some given data. That's why the abstract `Ansatz` class implements a `fit` function. I am using `scipy` here and the `curve_fit` method to fit the parameters to a function. Since `curve_fit` expects an array of parameters, I need to transform from my possibly nested and different Ansatz parameter types to a flat array. That's what `__flatten_attributes` does. The reverse of this function is `__set_attributes_from_flat_array`.
Since the `eval` method should not require to retype the parameters, but the `curve_fitting` requires them to be passed to the function, I created a wrapper for `eval` called `__eval_with_parameters` that sets the additional parameters as the class's attributes and then evaluates the Ansatz.

I'm interested in hearing your opinion on whether or not my approach is somewhat sensible. Are there concepts that would have simplified my implementation? Would you have done some typing differently?

Here's `Ansatz.py`

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Callable, Dict, Tuple, Optional

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


Array = npt.NDArray[np.float64]
Numeric = npt.ArrayLike


class Ansatz(ABC):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs: Numeric) -> None:

        # Store names and number of elements of **kwargs in self._dimensions
        self._dimensions: Dict[str, Tuple[int]] = {}

        # Set instance attributes
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            if np.isscalar(value):
                setattr(self, key, value)
                self._dimensions[key] = (1,)
            else:
                value_as_array: npt.NDArray[np.float64] = np.array(value)
                setattr(self, key, value_as_array)
                self._dimensions[key] = value_as_array.shape

        # Vectorized version of the Ansatz
        self.__eval_vectorized: Callable[[Array], Array] = np.vectorize(self.eval)

    @abstractmethod
    def eval(self, x: float) -> float:
        """Evaluate the Ansatz.

        Parameters
        ----------
        x : float
            Where to evaluate the Ansatz.

        Returns
        -------
        float
            The evaluated Ansatz.
        """
        pass

    def fit(self, x: Array, y: Array, plot: bool = False, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        """Fit the Ansatz to the data. Overwrite the instance attributes.
        Sets the instance attributes to the fitted parameters unless there is
        a RuntimeErrror. In that case, revert the instance attributes to the
        original values.

        Parameters
        ----------
        x : Array
            x-values of the data used for fitting.
        y : Array
            y-values of the data used for fitting.
        plot : bool, optional
            Whether or not to plot the data and fit, by default False
        """

        p0 = self.__flatten_attributes()
        try:
            p_opt, _ = curve_fit(
                self.__eval_with_parameters, x, y, p0=p0, *args, **kwargs
            )
            self.__set_attributes_from_flat_array(p_opt)
            if plot:
                t = np.linspace(np.min(x), np.max(x), 100)
                _, ax = plt.subplots()
                ax.plot(x, y, "o", label="data")
                ax.plot(t, self.__eval_vectorized(t), "-", label="fit")
                ax.set_title(f"{self.__class__.__name__} Ansatz")
                ax.set_xlabel("x")
                ax.set_ylabel("y")
                ax.legend()
                plt.show()

        except RuntimeError as e:
            print(e)
            self.__set_attributes_from_flat_array(p0)

    def __eval_with_parameters(self, x: Array, *args: float) -> Array:
        """Evaluate the Ansatz with the given parameters.
        Changes the instance attributes.

        Parameters
        ----------
        x : Array
            Where to evaluate the Ansatz.
        *args : float
            The parameters used to temporarily set the instance attributes to.

        Returns
        -------
        Array
            The evaluated Ansatz.
        """

        self.__set_attributes_from_flat_array(np.array(args))
        return self.__eval_vectorized(x)

    def __flatten_attributes(self) -> Array:
        """Return all instance attributes as a flattened array.

        Returns
        -------
        Array
            Flat array with all instance attributes.
        """
        flat_attributes = np.empty(0)
        for key, _ in self._dimensions.items():
            attr = getattr(self, key)
            if not np.isscalar(attr):
                attr = attr.flatten()
            flat_attributes = np.append(flat_attributes, attr)
        return flat_attributes

    def __set_attributes_from_flat_array(self, flat_attributes: Array) -> None:
        """Sets the instance attributes from a flattened array.

        Parameters
        ----------
        flat_attributes : Numeric
            Flat array with attributes to set.
        """
        counter = 0
        for key, shape in self._dimensions.items():
            n_elements = int(np.prod(shape))
            attr = flat_attributes[counter : counter + n_elements].reshape(shape)
            setattr(self, key, attr)
            counter += n_elements
```

And here are some derived implementations with a few runnable examples (I omitted the comments that describe the different Ansätze).

```py
from typing import Optional

import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt

from .Ansatz import Ansatz

Array = npt.NDArray[np.float64]
Numeric = npt.ArrayLike


class Poly(Ansatz):
    coefficients: Array

    def __init__(
        self, order: Optional[int], coefficients: Optional[Numeric] = None
    ) -> None:
        if coefficients is None:
            if order is not None:
                coefficients = np.zeros(order + 1)
            else:
                raise ValueError("Either order or coefficients must be given.")

        if coefficients is not None and order is not None:
            if np.size(coefficients) != order + 1:
                raise ValueError(
                    f"Order of polynomial ({order}) +1 does not match number of coefficients ({np.size(coefficients)})"
                )

        super().__init__(coefficients=coefficients)

    def eval(self, x: float) -> float:
        powers_of_x = [x**i for i in range(len(self.coefficients))]
        return np.dot(self.coefficients, powers_of_x)


class Exponential(Ansatz):
    y0: float
    rate: float

    def __init__(self, y0: float = 1.0, rate: float = 1.0):
        super().__init__(y0=y0, rate=rate)

    def eval(self, x: float) -> float:
        return self.y0 * np.exp(self.rate * x)


class Rational(Ansatz):
    offset: float
    enumerator: Array
    denominator: Array

    def __init__(
        self, offset: float = 0.0, enumerator: Numeric = 1.0, denominator: Numeric = 1.0
    ):
        assert np.size(enumerator) == np.size(denominator)
        super().__init__(offset=offset, enumerator=enumerator, denominator=denominator)

    def eval(self, x: float) -> float:
        powers_of_x = [x**i for i in range(len(self.enumerator))]
        return (
            np.dot(self.enumerator, powers_of_x) / np.dot(self.denominator, powers_of_x)
        ) + self.offset


if __name__ == "__main__":
    P = Poly(order=2, coefficients=[1, 2, 3])
    E = Exponential(y0=1.0, rate=2.0)
    R = Rational(offset=1.0, enumerator=[1, 2], denominator=[1, 1])

    x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
    y = np.random.randn(x.shape[0]) + x**2 - x**3 / 10

    P.fit(x, y, plot=True)
    E.fit(x, y, plot=True)
    R.fit(x, y, plot=True)
```

Thanks in advance for all feedback!

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Sorry, I should have read the guidelines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty good!

Overall you have reasonable types, especially `Array` (though that should only be declared once). But your use of `kwargs` and `setattr` interferes with that type safety. There are type-safe ways around this: one way would be for `Rational` to be a `@dataclass`, and for its `super` to call into `fields()` or `asdict()`. Or without dataclasses, maybe `__dict__` would work (so long as `Rational` stores `offset`, `enumerator` and `denominator` as members from its own constructor).

Though it's unlikely for `eval` to collide with the built-in `eval`, it's enough to confuse some syntax highlighters etc. Probably best to rename this.

This:

```
    powers_of_x = [x**i for i in range(len(self.enumerator))]
```

can be vectorised as

```
    powers_of_x = x ** np.arange(len(self.enumerator))
```

The `__main__` guard is not enough to exclude `P`, etc. from the global namespace. That code should be moved to a main function.

Don't `assert` in production code; raise an exception instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I Gave `fields` and `dataclass` a  try (see the **UPDATE** part of my question). I also included all further suggestions. It really does look cleaner with the `@dataclass` decorator.